# Deny Access to Folders but not Files in it

Tags: permissions, web, directory

I am currently on a shared host and my files and folders are placed inside "public_html". In this, I have a folder that consists more folders inside it along with many pdf files. So the folder looks like this:

FOLDER/folder1/xyz.pdf

FOLDER/folder2/abc.pdf

etc..etc..

I am trying to figure out a way to deny access to the folder directly through a browser but not deny access to the files in it. At the moment, when someone goes to my site as www.mysite.com/FOLDER, you can access the folder and see its contents through a browser itself. But I dont want to deny complete access to the folder since I have links to its pdf files in some of other pages on my site like: Click here

Can someone guide me on I can restrict the direct access to the folder but not deny access to its files plz?

EDIT:
I am thinking, do I just create an index.html file in every folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using htaccess and adding the IndexIgnore command:

IndexIgnore *

Put it in a file and call it  .htaccess   (Not .htacces.txt, only .htaccess)

Another option is to prevent only one kind of file from being indexed:

IndexIgnore *.pdf

You can ignore any file type:   " *.pdf *.zip *.jpg *.png *.html(bad idea! :P )"

I hope this helps :)

Comment: sorry...I dont quite understand. I already have an .htaccess file with various redirection and other commands in it. What do I do if I want to say deny access to "FolderXYZ" and not its pdf files in it, do I add something like: IndexIgnore FolderXYZ * ? Sorry if its sounds dumb..

Comment: Well, if you make the indexing ignore Everything,( IndexIgnore * ) it will be close to denying access to the folder. The files in it are able to be viewed only if you have the url ( site.com/folder/myfile.pdf).
Just do this:  IndexIgnore *   That will allow your site to link to them, but people will not be able to view the files in the folder.

Comment: Excellant! Thank you so much...It worked and that was exactly what I was after. I never knew about IndexIgnore before and its really useful. I now added "IndexIgnore *" to my .htaccess and when the folder is now accessed, I cant view anything in it but the direct link to its files still works! Thats awesome...thank you so much!

I also read this article in the mean time that helped me understand more. I found it off google. Here is the link if it helps out other newbies who wants to know more: http://www.maxi-pedia.com/IndexIgnore

Thankx again for you help AZInventor!

Answer (score 3):

Better solution will be to use

```
Options -Indexes
```

It will **forbid** the contents of a directory to be displayed if it has **no index** file. The best thing is that it will not display the header of the directory like

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Cheers, Chris